# How to attach state to dynamically generated NextUI Table Rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swr, nextui

I'm using Nextjs with NextUI. I have this JSX

```
    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Agora</h1>

            <Skeleton isLoaded={!isLoading} className="rounded-lg">
                <Table removeWrapper aria-label="demo agora table">
                    <TableHeader columns={columns}>
                        {(column) => <TableColumn key={column.key} align="center">{column.label}</TableColumn>}
                    </TableHeader>
                    <TableBody items={data} isLoading={isLoading}>
                        {(item: any) => (
                            <TableRow key={item.id}>
                                {(columnKey) => <TableCell>{renderCell(item, columnKey)}</TableCell>}
                            </TableRow>
                        )}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </Skeleton>

            <Button onPress={async () => {
                await addDefaultItem()
                mutate()
            }}>Add</Button>
        </main>
    )
}
```

I need `renderCode()` to return different JSX to each `<TableRow>` based on whether that row's edit state is true.
My first instinct was to turn the rows into a component and attach the edit state that way. But when I do that Nextui can't render correctly. Apparently the only children that `<TableBody>` accepts are `<TableRow>`'s.
So then I tried to create a state array in my parent component, but when I try to update the state array the component code runs again, undoing the state change. Full code is below.

```
'use strict'
'use client'
import {Button, ButtonGroup, getKeyValue} from "@nextui-org/react"
import {Table, TableHeader, TableColumn, TableBody, TableRow, TableCell, Skeleton} from "@nextui-org/react"
import React, { Key, useReducer, useState } from "react"
import useSWR from "swr"
import Item from "./item"

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

async function addDefaultItem() {
    const res = await fetch('/api/items', {
        method: 'PUT'
    })      
    if (!res.ok)
        console.log(res.status, res.statusText);
}

async function deleteItem(id: number) {
    const res = await fetch('api/items', {
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: id
        })
    })
    if (!res.ok)
        console.log(res.status, res.statusText)
}

const columns = [
    {
        key: 'id',
        label: 'ID'
    },
    {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'NAME'
    },
    {
        key: 'squad',
        label: 'KEY'
    },
    {
        key: 'rank',
        label: 'RANK'
    },
    {
        key: 'squadRank',
        label: 'SQUAD RANK'
    },
    {
        key: 'update',
        label: ''
    },
    {
        key: 'delete',
        label: ''
    }
]

export default function Home() {
    let {data, isLoading, mutate} = useSWR('/api/items', fetcher, {
        fallbackData: []
    })

    const idsToFalse = React.useCallback(function (data: Array<any>) {
            const arr: Array<boolean> = []
            data.forEach(d => {
                arr[d.id] = false
            })
            console.log('ids', arr)
            return arr
    }, [])

    let [edits, setEdits] = useState(idsToFalse(data))
    console.log('set', edits)

    const startEdit = React.useCallback(function(id: number) {
        console.log('start', edits)
        const newEdits: Array<boolean> = Array.from(edits)
        console.log('new1', newEdits)
        newEdits[id] = true
        console.log('new2', newEdits)
        setEdits(newEdits)
    }, [edits])

    const endEdit = React.useCallback(function(id: number) {
        const newEdits: Array<boolean> = Array.from(edits)
        newEdits[id] = false
        setEdits(newEdits)

    }, [edits])

    const renderCell = React.useCallback((item: any, columnKey: Key) => {
        var edit: boolean = edits[item.id]
        switch (columnKey) {
            case 'delete':
                return !edit ? (
                    <Button
                        color="danger"
                        variant="ghost"
                        onPress={async () => {
                            await deleteItem(item.id)
                            mutate()
                        }}
                    >
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                ) : (
                    <Button
                        color="danger"
                        variant="ghost"
                        onPress={async () => {
                            endEdit(item.id)
                        }}
                    >
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                );
            case 'update':
                return !edit ? (
                    <Button
                        color="warning"
                        variant="ghost"
                        onPress={() => {
                            startEdit(item.id)
                        }}
                    >
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                ) : (
                    <Button
                        color='success'
                        onPress={() => {
                            endEdit(item.id)
                        }}
                    >
                        Confirm
                    </Button>
                )
            default:
                return (
                    getKeyValue(item, columnKey)
                );
        }
    }, [mutate, edits, startEdit, endEdit])

    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Agora</h1>

            <Skeleton isLoaded={!isLoading} className="rounded-lg">
                <Table removeWrapper aria-label="demo agora table">
                    <TableHeader columns={columns}>
                        {(column) => <TableColumn key={column.key} align="center">{column.label}</TableColumn>}
                    </TableHeader>
                    <TableBody items={data} isLoading={isLoading}>
                        {(item: any) => (
                            <TableRow key={item.id}>
                                {(columnKey) => <TableCell>{renderCell(item, columnKey)}</TableCell>}
                            </TableRow>
                        )}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </Skeleton>

            <Button onPress={async () => {
                await addDefaultItem()
                mutate()
            }}>Add</Button>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve my predicament?